# SSRS Trigger to update Description with additional information

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to create a trigger that will update Description on SSRS for the record that has been edited.

I am trying to add schedule information into the Description column on SSRS on screen where you assign schedules to a report.

I have the below query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateDescription
ON [dbo].[Subscriptions]
AFTER INSERT,  UPDATE
AS
UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions
SET [Description] = a.Description + ' | Schedule: ' + d.Name
FROM dbo.Subscriptions a
LEFT JOIN dbo.Catalog b
ON a.Report_OID = b.ItemID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule c
ON b.ItemID = c.ReportID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Schedule d
ON c.ScheduleID = d.ScheduleID
WHERE
```

When that trigger is in place and I edit a report it changes the description for every schedule for all reports.... What sort of parameter could I add to the 'WHERE' statement at the end so it only edits the description for the schedule I am currently creating/updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to join onto INSERTED table, which holds all the records modified

```
INNER JOIN INSERTED as I ON dbo.Subscriptions.Id = I.Id
```

Comment: Hi, It seems that I don't have this table in my ReportServer db... I've just also realised that I am running SSRS 2012 not 2008 - would this be the reason for not having this table?

Comment: Inserted table is a special table created and managed by SQL Server automatically. Please see [Use inserted table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017). This table is created in Trigger execution time and can only be used in that window of time.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a `WHERE` clause, you should `INNER JOIN` to the INSERTED table.  This will only contain rows that were inserted into the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateDescription
ON [dbo].[Subscriptions]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions
SET [Description] = a.Description + ' | Schedule: ' + d.Name
FROM dbo.Subscriptions a
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.SubscriptionID = a.SubscriptionID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Catalog b ON a.Report_OID = b.ItemID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule c ON b.ItemID = c.ReportID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Schedule d ON c.ScheduleID = d.ScheduleID;
```

Comment: Hi, like mentioned above, in reply to @MadBert I can't seem to find that table.

Comment: The table only exists within the scope of a INSERT or UPDATE trigger.

Comment: That works thank you. Best answer goes to MadBert simply because he was a bit faster...